# Multiple HierarchicalMenu with same facets param in the one page but different window size

Tags: reactjs, algolia, instantsearch.js, react-instantsearch

We have two Filter components that use `connectHierarchicalMenu()` on one page. We would like to render one of them on bigger devices like desktops and one for tablets & mobile devices.

Expected behavior:
Users must able to open the page in desktop size and see <**BigFilter** /> component and when they resize the window to a smaller size like a tablet/mobile, we want to render <**SmallFilter** /> component.

We tried checking the **userAgent** & **window.innerWidth**  to prevent rendering both at the same time, but it seems they invoke together.

Imaginary sample code from our page:

```
const Example = () => {

  const THRESHOLD  = 1000;
  const isBrowser =  typeof window !== 'undefined';
  const isDesktop = isBrowser && (window.innerWidth ?? 0) > THRESHOLD;

  return (
    <div>
      {isDesktop && <BigFilter />}
      {!isDesktop && <SmallFilter />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

NOTE: We are using SSR and this is the reason I checked **window** object before using it.

I guess this is a very common scenario to have two different components for small & big devices, with the same facet reference. but I stuck with the following error:

```
Error: Cannot declare two hierarchical facets with the same name: `myExampleFacet`
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: i dont know if this is related to ssr but i couldn't replicate https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-hierarchical-0qd1is?file=/src/App.js

Comment: dynamic https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-hierarchical-dynamic-4x350g?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It is impossible that both components render at the same time with the code you have provided (if I'm not missing something). `isDesktop` and `!isDesktop` can't be both truthy: `{ isDesktop && <BigFilter /> }{ !isDesktop && <SmallFilter /> }`. Anyway, to be even more specific, I would change it to `{ isDesktop ? <BigFilter /> : <SmallFilter /> }`.

Comment: were you able to make progress?